# how to bind data individually in select using knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of select from observableArray, I when I choose a data in first select it will bind the data in next select. this is what it look like in my code.

html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Participants">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td>
           <select data-bind=" 
                options: $parent.AttendanceCodes, 
                optionsText: 'Text', 
                optionsValue: 'Value', 
                value:$parent.AttendanceCode,
                optionsCaption: 'select',
                event:{change: $parent.onchange_attendancecodes}">
           </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="reason" data-bind="options: $parent.AbsenceReasons, 
            optionsText: 'Text', 
            optionsValue: 'Value', 
            value: $parent.AbsenceReason"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

knockoutjs

```
    var viewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;

    self.AbsenceReasons = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AttendanceCodes = ko.observableArray(attendanceCodeList);
    self.Participants = ko.observableArray(participantsData);

    //event
    self.onchange_attendancecodes = function(){
        self.AbsenceReasons.removeAll();
        self.AbsenceReasons(absenceReasonsList);
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/comfreakph/xH8FU/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have in the code is that all of the second column selects are bound to **the same** "$parent.AbsenceReasons", so in the `change` event handler, once you change the self.AbsenceReasons, all of the second column selects will change because that is what they're bound to.

The solution is quite straight forward:

1. each participant should have its own "AbsenceReasons",
2. the second column select should bind to each individual participant's AbsenceReasons,
3. and `change` event handler only changes the specific participant's AbsenceReasons.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaux/wkQ6A/)

Comment: yes that's what I want. only the in same row will change. thanks

Comment: @comfreakph BTW, I updated my answer, I just saw you mentioned your problem in the title, please excuse me.